# Couchbase cluster setup without going through web console

Tags: couchbase

I am creating a 2 node Couchbase cluster. The basic installation is controlled by Puppets but once Couchbase is installed, I have to go to the web console and add the nodes to the cluster. Is there an automatic way to do the same.

Two more questions:

1) If I want to add a node to the system then is there a way to do it without accessing the web-console.

2) If I want to remove a node then how to remove it without losing the data.

NOTE: I am not asking for manual processes here but an automatic.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search in the couchbase docs brought up a REST interface for cluster administration:

> - Nodes are added to clusters with the `POST /controller/addNode` HTTP method and URI.
> - Nodes can be added to clusters with the `POST /node/controller/doJoinCluster` HTTP method and URI.
> - Nodes are removed from clusters with the `POST /controller/ejectNode` HTTP method and URI.

refer to: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-cluster-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the REST API, you can also [use the CLI](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/CBcli/cbcli-server-add.html) to do all of this.

Here is an example of adding one node, removing an existing node and rebalancing all in one command and all with no downtime:

```
$> /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli rebalance \
    -c <ip or hostname of an existing cluster node>:8091 \
    --server-add=<new node hostname>:8091 \
    --server-remove=<existing node hostname>:8091 \
    -u Administrator -p<your password>
```